# When where and how shall I create object of another class in OOP C#?

Tags: c#, oop, object

To my question, When, Where and How shall I create an object of a class. Say SomeOtherClass object in SomethingClass.

Which method is the best, and why? for example, I have a class

```
public class SomethingClass()
{
    SomeOtherClass obj;
    public SomethingClass()
    {
         obj = null;
    }
    public void methodOne()
    {
        obj = new SomeOtherClass();
        obj.someOtherClassMethodOne();
    }
    public void methodTwo()
    {
        obj = new SomeOtherClass();
        obj.someOtherClassMethodTwo();
    }
}
```

or I should do it like this?

```
public class SomethingClass()
{
    SomeOtherClass obj;
    public SomethingClass()
    {
      obj = new SomeOtherClass();
    }
    public methodOne()
    {
        obj.someOtherClassMethodOne();
        //use object here
    }
    public methodTwo()
    {
        obj.someOtherClassMethodTwo();
        //use object here
    }
}
```

What will happen "performance perspective" if there are 10 users accessing the same class at the time? Or just a one. Which one is better. Any helping material would be nice. Is there a better solution to it?

Comment: In this example, performance does not have any real impact here. it totally depends in your context of usage. A Constructor's purpose is to setup that class the way it needs to be before methods or props are invoked... so you can create a new instance of "obj" in the constructor and that's fine and valid. Doing it in the methods (One, two etc...) is fine too but you need to check for null before hand and the ordering of the calls maybe important, depending on your use case. I opt for constructor initialization/creation

Comment: Just one more question sir, in the first example, it is early binding and in the second example, it is late binding. Right?

Comment: @ITQ It would be rougly as appropriate to say in the first example it is gluten free, while in the other it's a vampire bat. You do yourself a terrible disservice by making up imaginative stories about what terminology might mean, instead of actually reading real documentation and finding out.

Comment: you don't need a lesson in C# - try reading about object oriented programming first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It all depends on what you are trying to do. If your goal is to create an instance of another class inside a class then here's how I'd do it below:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        SomethingClass somethingClass = new SomethingClass();
        somethingClass.PrintThisText("HEY THERE");
        //even though I'm calling .`PrintThisText` method here, this method will in turn call the `PrintText` method in `SomeOtherClass`
    }
}

public class SomethingClass
{
    readonly SomeOtherClass _someOtherClass;
    public SomethingClass ()
    {
        this._someOtherClass = new SomeOtherClass();
    }
    public void PrintThisText(string text)
    {
        this._someOtherClass.printText(text);
    }
}

public class SomeOtherClass
{
    public void printText (string text)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(text);
    }
}
```

Here's an example using Interface (might want to consider this)

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        SomethingClass somethingClass = new SomethingClass(new SomeOtherClass());
        somethingClass.doSomething("HEY THERE");

    }
}


public class SomethingClass
{
    DoStuff _doStuff;
    public SomethingClass(DoStuff doStuff)
    {
        this._doStuff = doStuff;
    }

    public void doSomething(string stuff)
    {
        _doStuff.PrintText(stuff);
    }
}

public class SomeOtherClass : DoStuff
{
    public void PrintText(string text)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("HEY THERE");
    }
}

public interface DoStuff
{
    void PrintText(string text);
}
```

Comment: Why are you using read-only in the first example? I really needed this kind of thing.

Comment: readonly is used to prevent another programmer from changing the value of variable once it's set.

Comment: if it answers your question, you can close it by marking it as answer

Answer (score 0):

As it already been said, it heavily depends on use case. If all those classes are simple and don't have any resource consuming mechanisms inside, the performance difference between those two examples should be negligible in most cases.

What isn't negligible, however, is how hard will it be to change and maintain your code in future. The first case is a good example how NOT to do it, as now you have to remember to `new SomeOtherClass()` in every method ever, and eventually, you will forget to do it, leading to null reference exceptions. It is usually a good practice for the constructor to return an instance of your class in a fully valid state, which includes initializing in some way all fields.

If `new SomeOtherClass();` happens to be slow and resource consuming, the first example will also be much slower, as every method call will have to do it again and again.

If, on the contrary, every method for some reason needs a new instance of `SomeOtherClass`, you can do it using properties:

```
SomeOtherClass Obj => new SomeOtherClass();
```

Now you can use it in methods like this:

```
public methodOne()
{
    Obj.someOtherClassMethodOne();
    //use object here
}
```

This way, every time something refers to Obj, a new instance of SomeOtherClass  will be created instead of reusing the old one.